# Debugging an Android app to the phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've gone through the page *[Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)*. My manifest has

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

My phone has *Menu* -> *Settings* -> *Applications* -> *Development* -> *USB Debugging* checked.

I have gone to the control panel on my Windows XP 64 bit installation and installed the USB drivers given to me by the SDK installer in `android-sdk_r05-windows\android-sdk-windows\usb_driver`. So my computer does recognize the Android device.

However.. when I run an app on Eclipse, it still insists on opening it up in an emulator rather than my phone. How can I fix that?

Comment: seems like you need to re-install the driver

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just picked up Android development again, and this is what worked for me using [HTC Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Hero) (2.1 update 1) on Eclipse ([v. 3.6 (Helios)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases), Service Release 1):

- Start up Eclipse
- Connect the phone
- Ensure USB debugging is enabled
- Set phone connection type to *HTC sync*,
  as opposed to charge only, etc.
  (You don't have to sync, but it need to be
  in this mode. A message will then be
  displayed in the task bar saying USB debugging is
  connected or something similar.
  Then follow AlexVolovoy's
  instructions (Right click on the
  Eclipse project -> *Run As* -> *Run Configuration* -> *Target* - Choose
  manual) and you should be good to go.
  Just remember to pick your phone from
  the list of targets.

Answer (score 6):

See if this helps:

- Right click on the Eclipse project -> *Run As* -> *Run Configuration* -> *Target* - *Choose manual*

The same goes for `Debug`.

Comment: Alex, I tried that and when it runs it presents this: http://i.imgur.com/ESeA1.png

It only has one device, the emulator, and doesn't display my phone at all.

Answer (score 5):

2 steps to follow

1. Enable USB debugging mode in your android phone. 
        settings > Applications > development > enable the "USB debugging" check box
2. Enable manual deployment target on eclipse.
        Right Click on project > Run As > run configurations > select the "Target" tab > select the "Deployment Target Selection Mode" as ""manual""

Now run your application normally and you will be asked to choose the device you wanna run.

Then you can simply select the device you wish to run (Using serial number of the phone, if there are many devices running at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

On the phone, go to *Settings* -> *Applications* -> *Development* and make sure USB Debugging is enabled. (This location is from a [Nexus One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_One), it may be different on other Android versions)

I'm not sure all phones support this, the [Android Dev Phone 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone#Android_Dev_Phone_1), [Android Dev Phone 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone#Android_Dev_Phone_2), and the Nexus One do.

Once you do this, the phone should appear in the dialog you posted a link to in your comment on Alex's answer.

Comment: I turned off USB Debugging as you mentioned but it still doesn't appear in the devices list on Eclipse.

Comment: err, sorry i meant that it should be checked, should be enabled, i'll edit to make it more clear.

If its not appearing its likely there is a driver issue, i don't use windows but use whatever the windows version of lsusb is and check that the device is found and the proper driver is loaded.  I think you'd have to look in the device manager to find this info in windows.

Comment: also make sure the phone is not set to appear as a USB drive, this will stop it from attaching to adb.

Comment: mark, i think the problem might actually be the OS recognizing my phone as a USB drive. any idea how i'd go about removing the recognition as a USB drive?

Comment: well, in linux when the phone is in debug mode it appears as a direct access SCSI device with some undefined endpoints which i assume are what adb uses.  If I were you i would just redo the USB driver installation instructions and maybe reboot windows and see if that fixes it.