# Debug on Samsung phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

How do I debug on a Samsung Galaxy S2? I have tried following the steps in the following topic, but it doesn't work. I dont get the option of changing usb connection type:

[Debugging an Android app to the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812442/debugging-android-app-to-the-phone)

I have already:

1. Set debuggable to true in the projects manifest
2. Checked the debug option on the phone
3. Connected the phone to the pc via. usb

Furthermore I cant see the phone in the Run as -> Run configuration -> Target tab -> Manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arcadia : have you installed the usb driver on your PC? First install Samsung Kies software then try the steps given by you. 
I may be wrong but try this. It may work.